# Particles: control conservation of momentum / inertia?

Tags: particles, force-fields

In Maya there's an attribute to reduce the inertia of particles, it's called Conserve. If Conserve is 1, the particles obey Newtonian mechanics. If Conserve is zero, none of the momentum from the previous frame or substep is applied to the current frame. Fractional values of Conserve are similar to a global dampening effect, but it's not the same thing.

Can Blender do anything other than conserve 100% of particle velocity from the previous frame? I want to be able to apply a constant force on every frame, such that the particle velocity does not accumulate and particles do not have any inertia. If the force is turned off, the particles stop moving.

Thanks